# Creating a WordPress style.css from package.json with Gulp

Tags: json, wordpress, gulp, task

I'm pretty new to Gulp, but I'm using it to manage my build process for creating WordPress themes. I have my package.json set up nicely, and I'd like my style.css to reflect that package.json. For example, if I have my `version` set to `0.0.2` in package.json, style.css should mirror that, after running my build task.

As a further example, if I have this as my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "new-site",
  "description": "A basic framework for a WordPress template",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": "https://github.com/revxx14/new-site",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

This would be my style.css, after running `gulp build`:

```
/*
Theme Name: new-site
Theme URI: https://github.com/revxx14/new-site
Description: A basic framework for a WordPress template
Version: 0.0.1
License: MIT
*/
```

I've already got the `json-file` package installed, as I'm using `gulp-file-include` to include the version number from package.json for cache busting purposes.

You can view my entire gulpfile here: https://github.com/revxx14/new-site/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: Pretty cool concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out, answer was super obvious.

Like I said, I'm already using `gulp-file-include` for added this very type of thing to my PHP files. For some reason I assumed this wouldn't work with CSS files, but it works totally fine.